Bounding Step Size in Lagrange Polynomial to obtain a certain accuracy
I'm trying to solve using Lagrange's Interpolation Polynomial for a bound of the step size needed to approximate the function $f(x) = log_{10}(x)$ between x=1 and x=10, to a tolerance of $10^{-6}$. So far, I know the error bound for the accuracy of the Lagrange polynomial is defined as the maximum of the following 'remainder term' :
$
\begin{align}
\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x))}{(n+1)!}(x-x_{0})(x-x_{1})...(x-x_{n})
\end{align}
$
My intuition to solve this question is to consider the above term with the bound preset to $10^{-6}$, and then solve for n:
$
\begin{align} 
|{\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x))}{(n+1)!}(x-x_{0})(x-x_{1})...(x-x_{n})}|\geq10^{-6}
\end{align}
$
Assuming equally spaced 'steps' for the polynomial and the nth derivative of the log function, we get something like:
$
\begin{align}
|{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{ln(10)*\xi(x)^{n}(n+1)!}(x-(1+\frac{9}{n}))(x-(1+\frac{9}{n}*2))...(x-(1+\frac{9}{n}*n))}|\geq10^{-6}
\end{align}
$
The first piece maximizes at $\xi(x)=1$ (minimizing the denominator), but the resulting term is too disgusting to solve for a minimum value of n (steps, or breaks within the interval). Does anyone have any clues from here (or another approach I can try?)

Are you aware of the Runge's phenomenon ?

You want your computed error bound to be lower than the given error threshold. The product can be bounded around some $x$ by separating out the two or 3 linear factors with roots closest to $x$ and taking worst-case values for all the others. The remaining bounds for the quadratic or cubic terms are simple. This will also replicate to some extend the Runge phenomenon, in the upper bounds, but not the lower ones.
